# Как увеличить длину массива до заданного значения

Tags: javascript

Есть такой массив:

```
var picDscr = [{
    url: picList[Math.floor(Math.random() * picList.length)],
    likes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 15,
    comments: commentsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * commentsList.length)],
    description: dscrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * dscrList.length)]
}]
```

Как увеличить длину массива до заданного значения через цикл? Например до 25 объектов.

Comment: `your_array.length = 25;` Читайте доку по работе с массивом http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Задачу я свою таким образом не решил, так как в этот цикл попадает все равно один объект массива `for (var i = 0; i < picDscr.length; i++) {
    var picElements = picTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    picElements.querySelector("img").src = picDscr[i].url;

    picElements.querySelector(".picture-likes").textContent = picDscr[i].likes;

    picElements.querySelector(".picture-comments").textContent = picDscr[i].comments;

    picItem.appendChild(picElements);
};`

Comment: А... вы хотите не просто расширить, а ещё и значения туда ложить? Тогда пишите функцию-прокладку. Например `function my_get(idx){  while (idx >= arr.length) arr[arr.length] = { your_data};  return arr[idx]; }` Я сразу не догадался. Но тогда вопрос отличается от заданного первоначально.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то:

```js
const picDscr = {
url: picList[Math.floor(Math.random() * picList.length)],
likes: Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 15,
comments: commentsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * commentsList.length)],
description: dscrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * dscrList.length)]
};

cosnt newArray = [...new Array(25)].map(() => picDscr)
```